# struggling with this simple java object oriented program

Tags: java, object

well simple to many of you i'm sure... 
basically we have to create a program to process tickets for a fair. A person can buy more than 1 ticket but they need a print-out at the end for each person attending.. 
ex. thanks! 
child: 1 
adult: 1 
total: $16

Our program should make just 1 object (use of arrays is not allowed) and when the object is created we will display the name of the county fair.

Kids under 12 pay $5. 
Adults pay $9.

a fee of $2 is added to the sale.

i'm just confused at how to set this up because apparently we need a data definition class and a use of a constructor but I only am familiar with doing this only in the Main...

thanks for any help!

Comment: RTM and also [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions).

Comment: nobody should disallow the usage of arrays.

Answer (score 1):

Make a Ticket class. It should take a variable age..
Use if statements to assign adult/child and make constant price for each.
As for the print out just after each order, ask if there are anymore tickets to be bought. If no, print out totals.

This is probably a homework assignment, I actually did this last year for APCS. Please just read your book and study the information. This forum is not to do your homework, its to help individuals develop an understanding of programming. Good luck.